# Populate a PHP Variable above a SQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql

May I ask if it is possible to echo a Php variable that is above the SQL database Statement that pulls the info that the above variable needs.  In this  case the varibale is called"$bidsfound".   I am using a workaround with a Required at the Top of the page but it means i am connecting to the same database twice. Thanks.

```
<span class="receivedbids-label" >Received Bids (<?php echo $bidsfound;?>) </span>
</div><!-- Card Head end -->

  <div class="card-body" >
  
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

etc etc..

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   
etc etc..
   // Number of rows Found
 $bidsfound = mysqli_num_rows($result);

?>
```

Comment: It will be better to connect only once at the top of the page and then set the variables for later. Why do you want to do it that way?

Comment: thanks for the reply i am a Newbee...   let me try what your suggestion .  I did it this way becuase I am echoing a Bootstrap card as search results below the SQL statement.

Comment: I need to work this one out with some test. Cheers

Comment: Just use a ternary operator. And why would there be 2 connection calls?

Comment: I will check out  the tenary operator function.      i will explain in more detail.  I  am echoing a search results  CSS DIV within the SQL statement results.  The echoed CSS formated DIV is about 30 lines long.   Its a list of  people profile cards.  They have to go somewhere specific.  I can even REQUIRE it and it works fine in the location I want.     I think I have found a way...  I will Require it at the top of a page and in the statement make the echoed content into a variable that can be placed anywhere in a page . i will test it.

Comment: I SOLVED IT.

Thanks I solved it.....In File A the SQL stamentment results DIV is placed in a variable. REQUIRE the SQL Statement and place it on the top of the page in file B. Then place the Variable anywhere on the page of file B :-)

Answer (score 0):

No. PHP is a **procedural** language - that means the state changes as the program is executed once - `echo $bidsfound` is executed before `$bidsfound = mysqli_num_rows($result);` and at the time it is executed, $bidsfound will have a different, or no, value.

It is a good idea to group together (or even separate) the application logic (mostly PHP) from the rendering (HTML) within your source code. Structuring logic into modules - functions or objects is the right way to achieve this.

> I am using a workaround with a Required at the Top of the page

There's a lot wrong with this. If you have any code in an included file which is executed inline (i.e. is not a function, variable, constant or object definition) then you're probably doing things wrong and creating security issues, limiting re-usability and making it more difficult to debug your code.

Comment: This post is hidden. It was deleted yesterday by Funk Forty Niner, Bhargav Rao♦.

I SOLVED IT.

Thanks I solved it.....In File A the SQL stamentment results DIV is placed in a variable. REQUIRE the SQL Statement and place it on the top of the page in file B. Then place the Variable anywhere on the page of file B :-)

Comment: Sharing scope across separate files is also an anti-pattern.